# MacBook Pro display is not working properly

Tags: display, macbook-pro

I have a MacBookPro 14", M1. Monterey.

There is something wrong with the display. Either it is too bright, or the color is too blue, or warm, or it is the new XDR technology, I don't know but I'm unable to look at this screen for more than a  few minutes. I don't think ıt is psychological because I have an older MacBookAir and I can work with that machine for hours. I tried to match the settings but with MacBookAir but the settings are different.

And, with MacBookAir I never had to touch the brightness controls. But with the Pro it never adjusts "correctly" to the light. I find myself trying to reduce or increase the brightness manually.

Is anyone else having a similar problem? Can you share your display settings? Mine is below:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried turning off True Tone?

Comment: If you like using True Tone, make sure you don't have any stickers or post-it notes on the margins of your display or over the camera cluster—you might be blocking the light sensors True Tone uses.